# Spark - Remove intersecting elements between two array type columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have dataframe like this

```
+---------+--------------------+----------------------------+
|     Name|                rem1|        quota               |
+---------+--------------------+----------------------------+
|Customer_3|[258, 259, 260, 2...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..500]|
|Customer_4|[18, 19, 20, 27, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..500]|
|Customer_5|[16, 17, 51, 52, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..500]|
|Customer_6|[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..500]|
|Customer_7|[0, 30, 31, 32, 3...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,..500]|
```

I would like to remove list value in rem1 from quota   and create as one new column. I have tried.

```
val dfleft = dfpci_remove2.withColumn("left",$"quota".filter($"rem1"))

<console>:123: error: value filter is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `filter` in a column in such way, you can write an `udf` as below

```
  val filterList = udf((a: Seq[Int], b: Seq[Int]) => a diff b)

  df.withColumn("left", filterList($"rem1", $"quota") )
```

This should give you the expected result.

Hope this helps!